# Scale up UIImageView (Storyboard Autoresizing)

Tags: ios, uiimageview, autolayout, storyboard, scale

I have a UIImageView in a Storyboard. The image used is square. The imageView width and height are equivalent. I want to take advantage of Autoresizing in Storyboard, so that on a small device the image is scaled down and on a large device the image is scaled up. When I test on a iPhone 5 the scaling is appropriate. However, when running on a iPad the results are different. The square is stretched, and this makes sense as the dimensions of the screen is different to the dimensions of the iPhone. How can I avoid this issue, is there a process in which I can scale the view as a whole up until the height is the same as the height of an iPad and then centre the view?

Note - The image has the same width and height and the content mode is set to 'Aspect Fit'

Comment: Without seeing your Autolayout constraints, it is really hard to help you solve this issue. If you set up a constraint on all imageviews to have the same width and a 1:1 ratio with themselves, it should be fine both on iPhones and iPads.

Comment: @DávidPásztor I have updated my question. I am only using the Autoresizing. The Image has the same width and height and the content mode is 'Aspect Fit'.

Comment: If you set up the constraints I suggested it should work fine.

Comment: @DávidPásztor I have been messing with constraints all day, with no luck. Autoresizing has been working for me so far. Is there a different method/solution

Comment: The best way to make an adaptive UI on iOS is by using Autolayout, so you should familiarize yourself with it, it's really helpful once you get the hang of it.

Comment: Using auto layout, you just need to set up two sets of height/width constraints, along with centering and aspect ratio. The first set of height/width is *greater than or equal to* the minimum size, with **a higher priority** than the set of constraints for *equal to* the maximum size. By doing this you are telling auto layout to **always** be a minimum size square for the smallest devices, but on larger devices the square **can** grow to the maximum size. can be

Comment: Only Autolayout and constraints is not enough. You must use Vary for Traits as stated on apple user interface docs. https://developer.apple.com/design/adaptivity/

Comment: just do one thing add your timetableView in a new UIView and for iPad screens just set the constraints for newView in which your tableview I embedded and constraints to be like leading - 100 , trailing- 100 bottom- 100 Top - 100 you will get desired result should I show you a demo For it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Follow this procedure

1) add a view in which all your content will be added so now you going to use 2 views NewView[with Content] and baseView

[image]

now time to add constraints to newView Do like this for leading, trailing,bottom and top [adding wr hr component]

[image]

Result For iPad

[image]

result for iPhone

[image]

Comment: Simple, what I want to do. Works. - I didn't even know you could add a view to a view.

Comment: yes we could we can add as many views we want using storyBoard and even programmatically.